# Has anyone made such horizontal scrolling list in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Is there any libraries to create such UI? I can't formulate right query search. Other items of list are visible while scrolling or viewing one of them

[image: Other items of list are visible while scrolling or viewing one of them]

Comment: This looks much like card than a list of elements

Answer (score 0):

I found satisfying library [custom view pager](https://github.com/kgnkbyl/CustomViewPager)

Answer (score 0):

[Horizontal View Pager](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/111?sort=rating) is what you are looking for. You can find many libraries such as [DiscreteScrollView](https://github.com/yarolegovich/DiscreteScrollView).